# Jquery: Iterate an array and find nodes with a specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of div elements:

```
var list = $('.divelement').get();
```

I want to use jQuery to find a specific element (that has an id that contains "hdnPK") in each of these div elements. Something like:

```
var elem1 = list[0].$("[id*='hdnPK']").get();
var elem2 = list[1].$("[id*='hdnPK']").get();
```

But you cant write it like i do above. How do you iterate through a regular array with jQuery?

Comment: Aren't IDs supposed to be unique across a document? What's the matter with using `$('#hdnPK')`? In a properly formed document, there should NEVER be more than one element with that ID. If you mean a 'class', then yeah, there can be multiples.

Comment: The ID is created dynamically so the first item might have "hdnPK1", the next one "hdnPK2" and so on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the element you're looking for is nested, do this:

```
$(list).find("[id*='hdnPK']")
```

Or if it is one at the top level, do this:

```
$(list).filter("[id*='hdnPK']")
```

---

Just wanted to make sure you knew that `.get()` pulls an Array of the DOM elements from the jQuery object. If you don't have any specific need for this, then you could do:

```
var list = $('.divelement');

list.find("[id*='hdnPK']")
// or
list.filter("[id*='hdnPK']")
```

---

Or if you don't need the intermediary cached set, then do this:

```
$('.divelement [id*="hdnPK"]') // for nested
$('.divelement[id*="hdnPK"]') // for top level
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".divelement").each(function() {

    var $specific_element = $(this).find("[id*='hdnPK']");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate an array in jquery same way you can in javascript genereally speaking:

```
var myarray = new Array(1,2,3,4); 
for (key in myArray){
     alert key; 
}
```

[How many ways can you iterate through an array in javascript?](http://ajaxian.com/archives/how-many-ways-can-you-iterate-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

A variation of [patrick dw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226009/jquery-iterate-an-array-and-find-nodes-with-a-specific-id/4226044#4226044)'s answer, you can use the `.eq()` or `.get()` methods to get a specific element:

```
var list = $('.divelement');
var secondElement = list.find("[id*='hdnPK']").eq(1); // return a jQuery-wrapped object
var thirdElement = list.find("[id*='hdnPK']").get(2); // returna a DOM element
```

Also, jQuery provides a convenient `.each()` method:

```
var list = $('.divelement');
list.find("[id*='hdnPK']").each(function() {
  // this inside this function refers to the currently iterated element
  console.debug(this); // write out the DOM element to the console
});
```

Comment: Also, replace `find()` with `filter()` if you're looking for elements that have the class and the id instead of elements contained within `.divelement`.